Find the maximum value of $\frac{2a^3+27c-9ab}{\lambda}$ as follows.
There exists three real numbers $a,b,$ and $c$ and positive real number $\lambda$ such that $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ has three real roots satisfies $x_2-x_1=\lambda$ and $2x_3<x_1+x_2$. Find the maximum value of
$$\frac{2a^3+27c-9ab}{\lambda}.$$
How to start solve this? I think Vieta doesn't enough. Any ideas?

You have to give your attempt, or source, or context etc.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
